# what is an efficient method for transposing N timing arrays into one master array?

Tags: arduino

This is an extremely niche problem, so I'll do my best to explain it in words:

Say you have an operation that requires negligible time (in my case, stepping a stepper motor once by pulsing the pins). I want to coordinate the movement of 6 individual motors with their own acceleration curve, but actuate them with the same micro controller. I also want the individual acceleration curves of the motors to be modifiable.

I'm using a Teensy 4.1, so this program will be written in Arduino language (near identical to C++).

My current approach to this problem is to generate six individual "delay" arrays for each motor. Essentially, their speed is controlled by the delay in between each pulse, and the angular distance traveled by the # of steps, or elements of each delay array. Something like this:

1 (P20) 1 (P20) 1 (P20) 1

2 (P30) 2 (P30) 2 (P30) 2

Where a 1 or 2 is the respective motor's step and a (PX) is a delay for X seconds.

I would like to write some master transposition function that turns the above into this:

1,2 (P20) 1 (P10) 2 (P10) 1,2 (P20) 1 (P10) 2

This array, when read by my actuation code would step motors 1 and 2 at the same time, wait 20 microseconds, step motor 1, 10 microseconds, step motor 2... etc.

It seems pretty simple when you do it for two motors, but for some reason I just can't wrap my head around making a completely modular version of this. In my case, it would need to merge 6 arrays into one.

I am also just wondering if anyone could think of a more elegant solution to this problem, as I am pretty new to programming and don't know all the features / capabilities of C++.

I have tried applying an iterative method, where you keep track of the current total delay elapsed and subtract it from the lowest next total delay of the different stepper arrays, then append the master array with that difference and update all the totals accordingly, but this approach always ends up too convoluted for me to follow.

Comment: Best you try to understand the Arduino "BlinkWithoutDelay" paradigm, which is not about *Blink*, but about *WithoutDelay*, and see that this can easily be expanded to multiple parallel and independent sequences. Each stepping a motor at its desired speed.

Answer (score 0):

Might I offer a different solution:

Use something like freeRTOS to and make individual threads to control each motor. That way you can define delays for each motor individually without having the extra complication of making a timing array.

The ESP32 has freeRTOS available in the Arduino definitions and is pretty easy to use. You could find a port for the Teensy 4.1

Here is a really nice tutorial for blinking LEDs at different rates. Your code should have a similar approach.
[freeRTOS ESP32 tutorial](https://www.digikey.in/en/maker/projects/introduction-to-rtos-solution-to-part-2-freertos/b3f84c9c9455439ca2dcb8ccfce9dec5)